# How to transform inconsistent yearly data to quinquennial averages?

Tags: r, for-loop, dataset, average, dplyr

I'm new to R and is trying to transform my yearly inconsisent dataset (data set does not necessarily contain data for every year, but do for some variables) into quinquennial averages. I'm trying to construct a for loop (although any method is appreacited) to generate a new variable for the average of the known years but crafting conditionally on years has shown to be difficult. 
In other words, if the dataset contains a value for all five years, it will generate the average of the five (same idea if it has data for 4-2 year) and if it has data for only one it will take the value of the single year while also constructing a new variable for time that equals the lowest/highest of the years.

I have tried to show this using simulated data (this is simulated for a 3 year average, but I hope same method applies for 5)

This is simulated data I have at this point, a variable indicating years, the data and countrycode.

```
df <- read.table(
text =
"Year, Data,Country
1,2,US
3,2,US
6,5,US
7,1,US
8,5,US
1,3,UK
2,5,UK
3,4,UK
4,3,UK
9,2,UK
", sep = ",", header = TRUE)
df
```

This is simulated data of what I would like a to achieve. Data is sorted by a 3 year average and there is constructed a new variable indicating year, which takes the value of the 'lowest' year.
(I made this 3 average and included the average calcucation for simplification)

```
df2 <- read.table(
text =
"Year, Data,Country,YearAvg,Average
1,2,US,1,4/2=2
3,2,US,4,5/1=5
6,5,US,7,3
7,1,US,NA,NA
8,5,US,NA,NA
1,3,UK,1,12/3=4
2,5,UK,4,3
3,4,UK,7,2
4,3,UK,NA,NA
9,2,UK,NA,NA
", sep = ",", header = TRUE)
df2
```

Any suggestion how this could be coded in R?

Edit:

```
df <- read.table(
text =
"year, Data,country
1,2,US
3,2,US
4,5,US
5,1,US
6,3,US
7,5,US
8,4,US
9,3,US
10,4,US
11,9,US
", sep = ",", header = TRUE)
df

df2 = setkey(setDT(df), year, country)[CJ(year = seq(min(year), max(year)), country = unique(country))
                                 ][ , avg := frollmean(Data, 5, align = "left", na.rm = TRUE), by = country
                                    ][order(country, year)
                                      ][(rowid(country) %% 5) == 1]
df2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `data.table` option.

- First would expand rows to fill in missing years for each country (so you will have years 1, 2, 3, etc. even if not data present)
- Then you `frollmean` to get a rolling average and ignore `NA` in `Data` (align left to average succeeding n years)
- You can select every 3 years with `(rowid(Country) %% 3) == 1` (and change 3 to 5 to get every 5 years)

Let me know if this works for what you have in mind.

```
library(data.table)

setkey(setDT(df), Year, Country)[CJ(Year = seq(min(Year), max(Year)), Country = unique(Country))
                                 ][ , avg := frollmean(Data, 3, align = "left", na.rm = TRUE), by = Country
                                    ][order(Country, Year)
                                      ][(rowid(Country) %% 3) == 1]
```

**Output**

```
   Year Data Country avg
1:    1    3      UK   4
2:    4    3      UK   3
3:    7   NA      UK   2
4:    1    2      US   2
5:    4   NA      US   5
6:    7    1      US   3
```

Comment: Coding works like a charm and thank you for the explanation too! 
Gotta keep that frollmean in mind in the future :)

Comment: At the last year per nation, I get a NA return although there is data available, any idea why?

Comment: Ahhh! I see what you mean in regards to align left, I will test that out asap. I'm pretty sure that's was the problem. I edited the original post to include the 'new' question but I will check with different aligns and write back asap. What I'm looking for is the last year to either take on the value of the single year (year 11 above) or the first year to take on the value of the year 1.

Comment: fill = last (year) takes the value of the last year of the dataset and applies it to the column 'data'.
Is there any way to extract the last value of the column 'data' conditional on a countrycode? 
In other words, fills in the value of data from the highest year (2017) conditional on a country code (ex. US)?

Comment: Can you pad with extra NA at the end? Try something like `max(year) + 4` in the `CJ` instead of just `max(year)`? This looks it should work, if n=5 years is desired, you want (n-1) + max.

Comment: Ben, you're a genius, adding extra years did the trick!
I'm really grateful for you taking your time to help a stranger, thank you!!!!